# Turn off CamelCase for class names in cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp, controller

In cakephp2.2, is it mandatory that a Class names should be written in CamelCase eg Exam2014.  Is there any way to get the output like exam2014.

Comment: `I want it like 'exam2014'` => Why? It is nice that you found your issue. Now all that's left is that you follow the conventions. This question was unnecessary IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just typed `why do controller names in cakephp start with a capital?` in http://google.com and first link that popped up was http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html

Excerpt from it says:

> Classes 
>   Class names should be written in CamelCase, for example:
>   `class ExampleClass { }`

There is your answer, I believe. You can read more at the link I provided for you.